# How to remove one item from an array using filter() in ReactJS - function not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a function to delete a recipe object from an array of recipes objects.

I am actually able to delete a recipe (remove it from the array called recipeList), but when I hit one delete button, it removes ALL of the recipes in the array. I only want to remove the one that I am clicking on.

I am pretty sure it has something to do with `this.state.id`. It's coming up undefined when I console.log it. It should be referring to the key/id of the recipe being deleted.

Anyone have any ideas what the issue could be?

This is the delete function:

```
handleDeleteRecipe = recipeId => {
// copy current list of items
const recipeList = [...this.state.recipeList];

//filter out item being deleted
const filteredList = recipeList.filter(recipe => this.state.id !== recipeId);
this.setState({recipeList: filteredList});
console.log('id: ' + this.state.id);
```

}

In the initial state, id is inside of an object called newRecipe and it is set to empty:

```
this.state = {
  recipeList: [],
  newRecipe: {
    title: '',
    source: '',
    servings: '',
    id: ''
  }
```

I have an add new recipe function where id is set to a random number between 1 and 1000. No idea if that would have anything to do with it. It is inside of the newRecipe object which then gets added to recipeList array.

```
handleAddNewRecipe = (title, source, servings, id) => {
const newRecipe = {
  title: title,
  source: source,
  servings: servings,
  id: (Math.floor(Math.random()* 1000))
```

This is where each recipe in the array gets mapped and returned as a Component. It has a key which is set to recipe.id.

```
{this.state.recipeList.map((recipe) => (
          <RecipeCardThumbnail
          title={recipe.title}
          servings={recipe.servings}
          key={recipe.id}
          handleDeleteRecipe={this.handleDeleteRecipe}
          />
        ))}
```

This is the delete button from the child component:

```
onClick={() => this.props.handleDeleteRecipe(this.props.id)}>Delete</button>
```

There's obviously something I am not understanding but I am not sure what. Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I also tried console.logging recipeList when I add my recipe to the array and the id showed up just fine. So I tried recipeList.id and the same issue occurred of all of the recipes getting removed.

EDIT AGAIN: I did an experiment and got rid of everything in the delete function except for the console.log. I tried logging `recipeList` and everything in the object was there. But when I logged `recipeList.id` or even `recipeList.title` they both showed up as undefined. I am still not sure what I am doing wrong though...

Answer (score 0):

this.state.id will return undefined because you don't have id directly under your state.
try this

```
handleDeleteRecipe = recipeId => {
// copy current list of items
const recipeList = [...this.state.recipeList];

//filter out item being deleted
const filteredList = recipeList.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== recipeId);
this.setState({recipeList: filteredList});
```

Comment: When I change it to recipe.id, nothing gets deleted. I tried to console.log recipe.id I got an error saying recipe is not defined.

Comment: are you sure that recipeList does have items inside?

Comment: recipeList starts out empty at the beginning but I tried console.logging each time I add a recipe and it does show every new item that is added. (see my edit at the bottom of my post)

Comment: try logging recipeList value before filtering on it

Comment: Okay, I just tried logging recipeList in my add recipe function (so before anything gets filtered). And everything shows up just fine.

Comment: copy paste what you got please?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter looks wrong you are never using the recipe object that you are filtering on. I would assume it should be `recipeList.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== recipeId)`

Also, you do not need to copy the array first... Array.filter will return a new array anyway

Comment: Thanks for the info about not needing to copy the list! I fixed that. When I change  this.state.id to recipe.id absolutely nothing gets removed. I am confused because it seems like that should work.